# How to combine 2 future sequences of type Seq[Either[A,B]]?

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

Suppose,there are 2 future sequences of type Future[Seq[A,B]]. How can I combine into one?

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Just contact both **Seqs**?

Comment: Are you sure about the two type parameters for Seq?

Answer (score 2):

You combined `Future`s using `flatMap`. So like:

```
futureA.flatMap(firstSequence => 
    futureB.map(secondSequence => firstSequence ++ secondSequence))
```

For comprehensions are syntax sugar for this:

```
for {
    firstSequence <- futureA
    secondSequence <- futureB
} yield firstSequence ++ secondSequence
```

---

This code will run your `Future`s sequentially if they've been lazy up until this point. So you may wish to allow them to run in parallel by assigning them to a val before the for comprehension.

```
val executingFutureA = futureA
val executingFutureB = futureB

for {
    firstSequence <- executingFutureA
    secondSequence <- executingFutureB
} yield firstSequence ++ secondSequence
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.sequence` to convert a sequence of `Future` into a single `Future` containing a sequence of the results of each `Future`. So in your case you can do this:

```
val a: Future[Seq[Either[A,B]]] = ???
val b: Future[Seq[Either[A,B]]] = ???

Future.sequence(Seq(a, b)).map(_.flatten) // => Seq[Either[A,B]]
```

The `flatten` operations converts the `Seq[Seq[Either[A,B]]]` into `Seq[Either[A,B]]`, but the results could be combined in other ways if required.

This solution is very flexible, but for a fixed number of `Seq[Future]` it is often better to use `flatMap`/`for` as explained in another answer.